# bootstrap - div overflow

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I recently started using bootstrap and I am not sure how to reproduce this layout.

[image: layout]

Right now, I tried with this basic layout but I don't know how to have the logo overflow the parent:

```
-header  
--container  
---row  
----col-md-2  
-----logo-img  
---col-md-10  
-----row  
------col-md-12  
-------title-h1  
-----row  
------col-md-12  
-------navbar
```

Any help?

**Update**

As suggested from the comments, I'm attaching the markup I started from:
http://www.bootply.com/0rp4zxhHWw

Comment: why not include the actual markup you've tried?

Comment: Also a jsfiddle, or better a bootply would be helpful

Comment: I would just position your logo `absolute`, and give header a `padding-left` equal to the width of the logo. Show us some real markup, or even better, set up an example, and I'll be happy to demonstrate. http://www.bootply.com/

Comment: @RoneyMichael - Please read the description of a tag before using it.

Comment: sure..sorry I didn't think about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `position: absolute;` to your logo.

```
#logo-wrapper img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Here is an updated bootply http://www.bootply.com/mw8dLEq1Uh